# Pointer error with no pointers

Tags: c

I am making a C program which reads either a circle or a square or a Triangle and calculates the area based on user input. I did it using structs. I am getting a few runtime errors, and some compiler errors.

Whenever I execute, the triangle option comes, and the area is not correct. I tried to flush the input buffer but it still happens, why is this?

Even though it compiles the compiler tells me:
"warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast[enabled by default].

What does this mean and how do you fix it? Also where are the pointers in this program as it is not immediately obvious to me/

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 struct point { int x, y; };

 struct shape {
 char shape_kind; 
 struct point centre;
 float area;
 union{
    struct{
     int height;
     int width;
 } rectangle;

 struct{
     int height;
     int width;
 } orthogonal_triangle;

 struct{
     int radius;
 } circle;
  }u;
};
int areaCalc(struct shape s, char shape_kind);

struct shape s;

 int main(shape_kind){
fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);


printf("\nWould you like to calulcate the area of a Triangle, Rectangle, or Circle?\n");
scanf("%s", &shape_kind);

fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);


if((shape_kind = "Triangle") || (shape_kind = "triangle")){
    printf("\nYou have selected Triangle. Please enter the base, followed by the height.\n");
    scanf("%d",&s.u.orthogonal_triangle);
    scanf("%d",&s.u.orthogonal_triangle);
}

else if((shape_kind = "Rectangle") || (shape_kind = "rectangle")){
    printf("\nYou have selected Rectangle. Please enter the width followed by the height.\n");
    scanf("%d",&s.u.rectangle.width);
    scanf("%d",&s.u.rectangle.height);
}

else if((shape_kind = "Circle") || (shape_kind = "circle")){
    printf("\nYou have entered Circle. Please enter the radius. \n");
    scanf("%d", &s.u.circle.radius);
}

else{
    printf("\nI am sorry, but your input could not be read. Please try  again.\n");
    main();
}

areaCalc(s,shape_kind);
return 0;
}

int areaCalc(struct shape s, char shape_kind){
if((shape_kind = "Rectangle") || (shape_kind = "rectangle")){
    s.area = s.u.rectangle.height*s.u.rectangle.width;
}

else if((shape_kind = "Triangle") || (shape_kind = "triangle")){
    s.area = s.u.orthogonal_triangle.height *1/2*s.u.orthogonal_triangle.width;
}

else if((shape_kind = "Circle") || (shape_kind = "circle")){
    s.area = s.u.circle.radius*s.u.circle.radius*3.1415926235;
}

else{
    printf("\nI'm sorry your input could not be read, please try again.\n");
    main();
}

printf("The total area of the %s is %f", shape_kind, s.area);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello don't dump us all your code, even without telling us in which line your error occurs. Please generate a minimal example in such cases.

Comment: You should definitively read up on strings and how to compare them in C.

Comment: Very poor formatting and sentence construction. Never dump all code here, just show us where the mistake is and also explain what you have tried to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several errors:

1. If you want to `scanf()` a string like "Triangle" or "Circle", you need an array:

   ```
    char shape_kind[80];
    ...
    scanf( "%s" shape_kind );
    /* or safer: */
    scanf( "%79s", shape_kind );
   ```
2. You cannot compare strings with `=`. That's an assignment (I guess these are the lines that lead to the compiler warning). You can use `==` for comparing integers, but for strings, you need `strcmp()`:

   ```
   if( strcmp( shape_kind, "Triangle" ) == 0 )
       ....
   ```

Btw:
for the next time, please indent your code correctly and if you have compiler errors or warnings, please tell us the lines where they occur

Comment: Ok thanks I will try this. 

Yeah sorry, it didn't paste well and I just joined two days ago so I'm not sure of the customs here yet.

Answer (score 1):

a) = is an assignment, == is comparison.
b) Strings (char-arrays), or arrays in general, can´t be compared element-wise with ==.
Use strncmp etc.
c) If a pointer error remains, tell us where

Comment: I have replaced everything with strcmp but pointer errors still remain on any line with an if statement. Here is an example of one statement.   

   else if(strcmp(shape_kind, "Circle") ==0){ 
      printf("\nYou have entered Circle. Please enter the radius. \n");
     scanf("%d", &s.u.circle.radius);
}
The error message reads, passing argument 1 of strcmp makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Oh, now i see. Well, Ingo Leonhardt gave you the direct solution already. Just an alternative: Use an 'enum' for such things as one of few predefined shapes.

Answer (score 0):

`shape_kind = "Triangle"` how you comapare string in `c` it's not valid.need `==` or use `strcmp`

Also `scanf("%s", &shape_kind);` not valid remove `&` i know it's lead warning but warning also lead error when it grows.

Also `int areaCalc(struct shape s, char shape_kind)` not valid to receive `shape_kind` need 
`char* shape_kind` And declared `char shape_kind[100]` in your main or global first.

Also you say that `Even though it compiles the compiler tells me: "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast[enabled by default].`  it say because you not compare string at every `shape_kind` comparison but you just assign pointer of string to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

To compare strings you will need `strcmp` oder `strncmp`.

For example `strcmp`:

```
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

> Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the
>   strings:  A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.  A value
>   greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not
>   match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than
>   zero indicates the opposite.

Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/?kw=strcmp).

```
if (strcmp (str1,str2) == 0) { /* strings are equal */ }
```